# Will these two segments of the circuit interact?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current

[image]

Let us simplify the given circuit.

[image]

Consider I2 to be the dependent current source. I couldn't get the square shape of the dependent current source on LTspice.

Now, let us begin our analysis. I think that the current will flow in this way.

[image]

Same colors indicate same current. Notice that no current is flowing from segment 1 to segment 2 and vice versa. Is my analysis correct?

Comment: No current can flow between them. But they interact in the sense that there is a dependency. I guess this gets down to the meaning ascribed to words and phrases.

Comment: Seems to be quite "text-book" like.  As a matter of fact that's exactly what it is right?

Comment: In your LTspice schematic, where does the off-page wires go to? In the homework assignment there is nothing else connected.

Comment: @winny I just put them there for no reason. They lead nowwhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're intending the simulation to work, not only do you have distrcting wires that go nowhere on left and right (which won't affect the simulation, but could hamper understanding) and a missing ground (at least one node should be grounded) but there is a missing connection that will result in incorrect results:

[image]

As @periblepsis effectively answered in a comment, there is an effect of the left hand part of the circuit on the right hand, a dependency, even though no current flows between them. That effect is a result of the *dependent* curent source.